# Autogenerate table for gallery

Tags: php

I  have a script that calls all photos in a folder and list them, but right now the script list all photos in same row.

I need them to be placed in a table like:

```
<table>
<tr><td>photo 1</td><td>photo 2</td><td>photo 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>photo 4</td><td>photo 5</td><td>photo 6</td></tr>
<tr><td>photo 7</td><td>photo 8</td><td>photo 9</td></tr>
</table>
```

and that way it continues until there are no more photos. The codes that show the photos looks like:

```
<?php
// loop through the array of files and print them all in a list
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    $extension = substr($dirArray[$index], -3);
    if ($extension == ('jpg' | 'JPG')){ // list only jpgs and JPG

        echo '<li><img src=" thumbnail/' . $dirArray[$index] . '" alt="Image" /><span>' . $dirArray[$index] . '</span>';
    }   
}
?>
```

Can some please help me how to fix this?

Comment: The idea here is that you try and do what you want to do, AND THEN if you have problems you ask a question about your problem. You **dont** show a **completely unrelated piece of code** and expect us to do **all the work for you**

Comment: Can you provide `I have a script that calls all photos in a folder and list them. But right now the script list all photos in same raw.`? If you show us your actual problem (what you have vs what you want) we are far more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like that:

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
$column = 0;
$closed = false;
// loop through the array of files and print them all in a list
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
$extension = substr($dirArray[$index], -3);
if ($extension == ('jpg' | 'JPG')){ // list only jpgs and JPG
 if($column === 0) { 
     echo "<tr>";
     $closed = false;
 }
echo '<td><img src=" thumbnail/' . $dirArray[$index] . '" alt="Image" /><span>' . $dirArray[$index] . '</span></td>';
$column++;
if($column === 3) {
  echo "</tr>";
  $column = 0;
  $closed = true;
}
}   
}

if(!$closed) {
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Please note my comment above. Answering blatent **do it for me** questions only encourages more questions like this

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do this with PHP and render it to HTML:

Create an array with all images:

```
$images = [];
foreach(dirArray as $file) {
    $extension = substr($file, -3);
    if ($extension == ('jpg' | 'JPG')){
        $images[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Then you can create chunks out of that array (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
$columns = 3;
$rows = array_chunk($images,$columns);
```

Then render your table:

```
$output = '<table>';
$i = 0;
foreach ( $rows as $row) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $file)
    {
        $output .= '<td><img src="thumbnail/' . $file . '" alt="Image" /><span>' . $file . '</span></td>';
    }

    //Add extra empty cells
    if ($i === count($rows) - 1) {
            $output .= str_repeat('<td>&nbsp;</td>', $columns - count($row));
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';

    $i++;
}
$output .= '</table>';

echo $output;
```

I would prefer not working with a table but use a responsive grid system ( http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/). 
You can still use the code above but replace the table parts with 's with the right classes.

Comment: Please note my comment above. Answering blatent **do it for me** questions only encourages more questions like this. Not my DV though